# How to know that some text is entered as well as cursor has come out of textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know if there is any event or way to know that some text has been entered into the textarea and also the user has come of the textarea, so that i can invoke some text like "success".

For the some values in the textarea i think we can do through val() function. But how to know that user has come out of the Textarea

My code is like:

```
<input type="textarea" id="link1"></textarea>
```

Comment: To know when text has been entered you can use the `keypress` event. To detect when focus has been lost, you can use `blur`.

Comment: On the blur event, check the `length` of the entered text and that would tell you if something was entered or not when the cursor left the textarea

Comment: you dont need the keypress event, it will only make the solution less elegant. just use blur and check the value.length in that event.

Comment: ***user has come out of the Textarea*** so looks like user is confined in the TextArea initially?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!$("#link1").val()) {
    // textarea is empty
}
```

You can also use $.trim to make sure the element doesn't contain only white-space:

```
if (!$.trim($("#link1").val())) {
    // textarea is empty or contains only white-space
}
```

and for detecting when user comes out of textarea

```
$('#link1').focusout(function() {
    alert(this.id + " focus out");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to catch the onblur event and then check the value.length to see if there is a value added to the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

textarea should be like

```
<textarea id="link1"></textarea>
```

events you are searching are `onkeyup`, `onfocus` and `onblur`

Answer (score 1):

Using onKeyPress it can be detected weather some text has been entered
and onBlur it can be detected weather the user has come of the textarea

```
<input type="textarea" id="link1" onBlur = blured() onKeyPress = pressed()></textarea>
```